# What does git log show me?

Tags: git

I'm missing something.  I used to use Mercurial and would look at the revision history of the repo with `hg log`.  Simple: **all** changesets ever made in the repo are shown.

Now I'm using git.  I'm pretty excited about learning the new tool, but I'm confused by what I'm seeing with `git log`.  I've done some changes and made some commits.  Another person has created a revision and committed as well.  I pulled from his repository.  I do a `git log` and his changeset (maybe it's called "commit" in git) isn't in the list.  If I explicitly list his hash number (ie, `git log <hash>`), it shows up at the top.  So it **is** in my repo, but I don't understand how git is deciding to show me what it does when I call `git log`.

I look at the `git help log`, but it says in the description that it "shows the commit logs."  From my perspective, that's incorrect.  Or perhaps incomplete because in reality it shows some subset of them.  But I don't know what subset nor how it determines what to show.

Can someone explain `git log` to me?

Update

btw: One of the first things I had tried was --all, and I see now that many people suggest it.  But that doesn't show it either:

```
$ git log | grep fb2a17c5fb08498e7f2ab364931fddc379be106f 
$ git log --all | grep fb2a17c5fb08498e7f2ab364931fddc379be106f 
$ git log fb2a17c5fb08498e7f2ab364931fddc379be106f  | grep fb2a17c5fb08498e7f2ab364931fddc379be106f 
commit fb2a17c5fb08498e7f2ab364931fddc379be106f
```

Comment: I don't believe I can explain `git log`, but I have `git gl` aliased to `git log --graph --all --decorate --sparse`. This gets functionality close, but not identical, to Mercurial's `hg gl` with the graphlog extension.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There is an implied argument to `git log` when you don't specify a reference or set of references. It is the current head. So

```
git log
```

expands to

```
git log HEAD
```

which means show me all the commits reachable from the current HEAD (where your next commit will attach).

In order to see your colleague's work, you can

```
git log origin/master
```

assuming you are both working on master and you fetched already.

In git, fetch means get the commits from the remote **but don't update any of my local branches**. `git pull` will do fetch and then merge your branch with what it fetched. It is a good idea to fetch, inspect what was done and then merge or rebase or even reject what was done with a force push - depends on the situation and your workflow.

typically, to see what was done on the remote after a fetch you can

```
git log ..origin/master
```

this really expands to

```
git log HEAD..origin/master
```

the `..` operator is short hand for combining "exclude reachable commits from this reference" and "include reachable commits from this reference". So it could also be written like this:

```
git log ^HEAD origin/master
```

the `^` at the beginning of a reference means exclude the commits reachable from here. In this case it means what you have reachable from where you are. The result will be a list of the commits on this branch just fetched from the server.

Instead of listing all the branches and remote branches as arguments to `git log`, you can just use the `--all` parameter:

```
git log --all
```

which will show all commits reachable from all branches (local and remote tracking) and tags.

`git log` is a very powerful command due to how it allows you to do set based reductions of what commits you want to see. `..` is a good syntax to know. There is also `...` which says to include commits from both the branches specified down to their common ancestor.

This walking of history is what makes git so powerful and able to support so many interesting workflows.

**UPDATE:**

When git encounters commits that are identical in terms of what is contained in the tree stored there with it's parent, it will not list the commit when it walks a merge.

```
git log --all --sparse
```

will not exclude those commits.

see the history simplification section of http://linux.die.net/man/1/git-log

It could also mean that you reset a branch or your friend did and fetching again has lost that reference. When you do git log with the sha1, what is the output if you add --decorate to it? Also try `git log --walk-reflogs`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  I updated the question - note that the git log --all doesn't show me the revision I'm looking for.  When I explicitly pass it to log, it shows up.

Comment: git log sometimes hides identical commits. If the tree is the same, it won't list it. Add the `--sparse` parameter to list those as well.

Answer (score 1):

`git log` without any further explicit arguments shows you the history of the commit you currently have checked out. If you want to look at other branches or commits, you have to tell `git log` what you want to look at.

```
git log --all
```

should show all revisions on all branches.

There are quite a few good tutorials out there for easy googling.

Answer (score 0):

You're right --- by default git log only shows you a subset of commits.  By default git log only shows commits visible from the tip of your current branch.  Your friend's commit isn't in your current branch yet, so it does not show up in git log.

Comment: when in detached head mode, you don't have a current branch.